# want to display all activites under all services using php

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php 

include("connection.php") 

$serviceid = "select * from services";
$servicevalue = $conn->query($serviceid) or die ($conn->error.__LINE__);
$activityid = "select * from activity";
$activityvalue = $conn->query($activityid) or die ($conn->error.__LINE__);
$perid = "select * from perodicity";
$pervalue = $conn->query($perid) or die ($conn->error.__LINE__);

while($row=$servicevalue->fetch_assoc()) :

?>

<input name="activity[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" id="" />

<?php 
    echo $row['servicename'];
    echo "<br>";
?>

<br><br>

<?php while($row=$activityvalue->fetch_assoc()) :?>

    <input name="activity[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />

<?php 
    $activity=$row['nameofactivity']; 
    echo "$activity";
    echo "<br>";                                                                        
    endwhile;
?>
<br>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

**my output :**

- 1. incometax
- form
- 1. incometax
- return
- 2.GST
- form
- 2.GST
- return

**I Want**

- 1.Incometax
- form
- Return
- 2.GST
- form
- return

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump($servicevalue);` and `var_dump($activityvalue);`?

Answer (score 0):

It's because in both `while()` loops you assign a value to the same variable - `$row`. In your second `while()` loop, rename your variable to something like `$row2` and see if it fixes your problem.

**Edit**
Thinking too quickly, what about this:

```
<?php 
include("connection.php");

// Collect services.
$serviceid = "select * from services";
$servicevalue = $conn->query($serviceid) or die ($conn->error.__LINE__);
$services = [];
while ($row = $servicevalue->fetch_assoc()) {
    $services[] = $row;
}

// Collect activities.
$activityid = "select * from activity";
$activityvalue = $conn->query($activityid) or die ($conn->error.__LINE__);
$activities = [];
while ($row = $activityvalue->fetch_assoc()) {
    $activities[] = $row;
}

// Collect something else?
$perid = "select * from perodicity";
$pervalue = $conn->query($perid) or die ($conn->error.__LINE__);
$pers = [];
while ($row = $pervalue->fetch_assoc()) {
    $pers[] = $row;
}

foreach ($services as $service):
?>

    <input name="activity[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $service['id']; ?>" id="" />

    <?php 
    echo $service['servicename'];
    echo "<br>";
    ?>

    <br><br>

    <?php foreach ($activities as $activity) : ?>

        <input name="activity[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $activity['id']; ?>" />

        <?php 
        echo $activity['nameofactivity'];
        echo "<br>";                                                                        
    endforeach;
    ?>
    <br>
<?php 
endforeach;
```

Changes: we first collect all services and activities. Then we loop through all services and for each service through all activities, and we output them.

Comment: My bad, this is actually an answer that doesn't solve anything, I was thinking a bit too quickly.